# Spring boot - return 403 Forbidden instead of redirect to login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

In Spring Boot web application I have the following security configuration:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off   
    http
        .headers().frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority(Authority.Type.ROLE_ADMIN.getName())
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Right now, when I'm trying to access the example url `/api/v1.0/user`, it redirects me to the `/api/login` page.

How to configure this in order to return `403 Forbidden` instead of redirect to login page ?

Comment: Guess you need to write your AuthenticationEntryPoint

Comment: @Tong thanks ! I have added `.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())` to my configuration and now it works as expected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a community Answer:

**Problem:**

*Forbidden urls were returning the login page content (instead of a 403 status code).*

**I Had this code:**

```
...
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/uri/**").hasAuthority("SOME_ROLE");
```

**Changed with Tong's suggestion:**

```
...
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/uri/**").hasAuthority("SOME_ROLE");
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me. Every unauthorized request was redirecting to the login page, whether for the /api/* RESTful requests or web pages.

Here's what did work: creating a public endpoint that produces the 403 error and modifying an existing filter so that, if the URI contains "/api" and there's no authenticated Principal, it redirects the request to the custom 403 handler.

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/error")
public class ApiErrorHandlerController {

   @RequestMapping("/403")
   public ResponseEntity<String> forbidden403(){
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
   }

}
```

The filter:

```
SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) 
                ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession()
                        .getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");

if (sci == null && ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI().indexOf("/api/") == 0 ){
   request = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
                   @Override
                   public String getRequestURI() {
                    return "/api/error/403";
                   }
             };
}
```

And, of course, the Spring Security rule:

```
...
authz.requestMatchers("/api/error/403").permitAll()
...
```